# How Create a hive external table with parquet format

Tags: sql, hive, hdfs, hiveql, impala

I am trying to create an external table in hive with the following query in HDFS.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `post` (
    FileSK STRING,
    OriginalSK STRING,
    FileStatus STRING,
    TransactionType STRING,
    TransactionDate STRING
   )
  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  STORED AS PARQUET TBLPROPERTIES("Parquet.compression"="SNAPPY")
  LOCATION 'hdfs://.../post'
```

getting error

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 11:2
> missing EOF at 'LOCATION' near ')'

What is the best way to create a HIVE external table with data stored in parquet format?

Comment: have you tried removing location clause and let it get created in default location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to create table after removing property TBLPROPERTIES("Parquet.compression"="SNAPPY")

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `post` (
    FileSK STRING,
    OriginalSK STRING,
    FileStatus STRING,
    TransactionType STRING,
    TransactionDate STRING
   )
  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  STORED AS PARQUET,
  LOCATION 'hdfs://.../post'
```